# XMPPFramework - Message not sent

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am newbie to `iOS`. I am building an app using `XMPPFramework`. But I am stuck up in a problem with last few days. Can't find any solution. The problem is when I want to send a message to any specific id, the message does not get sent. The action method for sending message is:

```
- (IBAction)sendMsg:(id)sender 
{
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSString *messageStr = self.msgField.text;

    if ([messageStr length] > 0) 
    {

        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue:messageStr];

        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"abc.codemen@gmail.com"];
        [message addChild:body];    
        [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
    }
}
```

Here is the sendElement method for sending `NSXMLElement` in my `XMPPStream.m`:

```
- (void)sendElement:(NSXMLElement *)element
{
    if (element == nil)
        return;

    dispatch_block_t block = ^{ @autoreleasepool {
        if (state == STATE_XMPP_CONNECTED)
            [self sendElement:element withTag:TAG_XMPP_WRITE_STREAM];
    }};

    if (dispatch_get_current_queue() == xmppQueue)
            block();
    else
            dispatch_async(xmppQueue, block);
}
```

But I found that the method call for message sending is not entering into the if statement!

```
if (state == STATE_XMPP_CONNECTED)
{
    [self sendElement:element withTag:TAG_XMPP_WRITE_STREAM];
}
```

I think this is why I can't send a message to any id. Please help me by suggesting if I am wrong or right, and how can I solve the problem?

Here is my Appdelegate class:

```
#import "iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate.h"
#import "GCDAsyncSocket.h"
#import "XMPP.h"
#import "XMPPReconnect.h"
#import "XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage.h"
#import "XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage.h"
#import "XMPPvCardAvatarModule.h"
#import "XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.h"
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#import "ParentLoginViewController.h"
#import "Child.h"

// Log levels: off, error, warn, info, verbose
#if DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_INFO;
#endif

@implementation iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate

//@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize xmppStream;
@synthesize xmppReconnect;
@synthesize xmppRoster;
@synthesize xmppRosterStorage;
@synthesize xmppvCardTempModule;
@synthesize xmppvCardAvatarModule;
@synthesize xmppCapabilities;
@synthesize xmppCapabilitiesStorage;
@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;

static iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate *sharedInstance = nil;

// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
+ (iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate *)sharedInstance {
if (sharedInstance == nil) {
    sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
}

return sharedInstance;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

[self setupStream];

if (![self connect])
{
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.0 *       NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            ParentLoginViewController *parent = [[ParentLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParentLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
            [navigationController presentModalViewController:parent  animated:YES];
        });
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[self teardownStream];
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext_roster
{
    return [xmppRosterStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext_capabilities
{
    return [xmppCapabilitiesStorage mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
}

- (void)setupStream
{
    NSAssert(xmppStream == nil, @"Method setupStream invoked multiple times");

    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];

    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    {
        xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;
    }
    #endif

    xmppReconnect = [[XMPPReconnect alloc] init];

    xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init];

    xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];

    xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
    xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;

    xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc]   initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];

    xmppvCardAvatarModule = [[XMPPvCardAvatarModule alloc] initWithvCardTempModule:xmppvCardTempModule];

    xmppCapabilitiesStorage = [XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    xmppCapabilities = [[XMPPCapabilities alloc] initWithCapabilitiesStorage:xmppCapabilitiesStorage];

    xmppCapabilities.autoFetchHashedCapabilities = YES;
    xmppCapabilities.autoFetchNonHashedCapabilities = NO;

    // Activate XMPP modules

    [xmppReconnect         activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppRoster            activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppvCardTempModule   activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppvCardAvatarModule activate:xmppStream];
    [xmppCapabilities      activate:xmppStream];

    // Add ourself as a delegate to anything we may be interested in

    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppStream setHostName:@"talk.google.com"];
    [xmppStream setHostPort:5222];

    // You may need to alter these settings depending on the server you're connecting to
    allowSelfSignedCertificates = NO;
    allowSSLHostNameMismatch = NO;
}

- (void)teardownStream
{
    [xmppStream removeDelegate:self];
    [xmppRoster removeDelegate:self];

    [xmppReconnect         deactivate];
    [xmppRoster            deactivate];
    [xmppvCardTempModule   deactivate];
    [xmppvCardAvatarModule deactivate];
    [xmppCapabilities      deactivate];

    [xmppStream disconnect];

    xmppStream = nil;
    xmppReconnect = nil;
    xmppRoster = nil;
    xmppRosterStorage = nil;
    xmppvCardStorage = nil;
    xmppvCardTempModule = nil;
    xmppvCardAvatarModule = nil;
    xmppCapabilities = nil;
    xmppCapabilitiesStorage = nil;
}

- (void)goOnline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence]; // type="available" is implicit

    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}

- (void)goOffline
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:@"unavailable"];

    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}


- (BOOL)connect
{
    if (![xmppStream isDisconnected]) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSString *myJID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyJID];
    NSString *myPassword = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyPassword];

    if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
        return NO;
    }

    [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
    password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![xmppStream connect:&error])
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error connecting" 
                                                        message:@"See console for error details." 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        DDLogError(@"Error connecting: %@", error);

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)disconnect
{
    [self goOffline];
    [xmppStream disconnect];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}


- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket 
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary  *)settings
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    if (allowSelfSignedCertificates)
    {
        [settings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(NSString  *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
    }

    if (allowSSLHostNameMismatch)
    {
        [settings setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
    }

    else
    {
        NSString *expectedCertName = nil;

        NSString *serverDomain = xmppStream.hostName;
        NSString *virtualDomain = [xmppStream.myJID domain];

        if ([serverDomain isEqualToString:@"talk.google.com"])
        {
            if ([virtualDomain isEqualToString:@"gmail.com"])
            {
                expectedCertName = virtualDomain;
            }

            else
            {
                expectedCertName = serverDomain;
            }
        }

        else if (serverDomain == nil)
        {
            expectedCertName = virtualDomain;
        }

        else
        {
            expectedCertName = serverDomain;
        }

        if (expectedCertName)
        {
            [settings setObject:expectedCertName forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
        }
    }
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidSecure:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    isXmppConnected = YES;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![[self xmppStream] authenticateWithPassword:password error:&error])
    {
        DDLogError(@"Error authenticating: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    [self goOnline];
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didNotAuthenticate:(NSXMLElement *)error
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    return NO;
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    // A simple example of inbound message handling.

    if ([message isChatMessageWithBody])
    {
        NSLog(@"Message is: %@",message); 

        XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message      from]                                                                  xmppStream:xmppStream managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

        NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
        NSString *displayName = [user displayName];

        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayName
                                                          message:body 
                                                         delegate:nil 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        else
        {
            // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
            localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n\n%@",displayName,body];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
        }
    }
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didSendMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{  
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [presence fromStr]);
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveError:(id)error
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    if (!isXmppConnected)
    {
        DDLogError(@"Unable to connect to server. Check xmppStream.hostName");
    }
}

#pragma mark XMPPRosterDelegate

- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceiveBuddyRequest:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[presence from]
                                                         xmppStream:xmppStream
                                               managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

    NSString *displayName = [user displayName];
    NSString *jidStrBare = [presence fromStr];
    NSString *body = nil;

    if (![displayName isEqualToString:jidStrBare])
    {
        body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Buddy request from %@ <%@>", displayName, jidStrBare];
    }
    else
    {
        body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Buddy request from %@", displayName];
    }


    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayName
                                                        message:body 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Not implemented"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    } 
    else 
    {
        // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"Not implemented";
        localNotification.alertBody = body;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
}

-(void)sendingMessage
{       
    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:@"Hello brother"];

    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"abc.codemen@gmail.com"];
    [message addChild:body];

    [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];

    NSLog(@"message sending! : %@",message);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to xmpp framework, then you should have to first set up server( like Ejabbered, openfire) for chat client then you have to configure it for chat. You will find very nice tutorial for this from following link which are derived in four parts. Please take a look at this tutorial step by step:-

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/

Comment: Thanks bro. Actually i want to implement the chat functionality for gtalk. Can i do so with Jabber?

Comment: @John I have not checked it with gtalk, but i think gtalk should work with Jabber

Comment: Sunil, it will be better if i could know, what is the problem with my code, since i am working with the project since many days. And since i am not sure whether i can login with the gmail id & password or not if i use jabber, so it will be quite time consuming for me to start with Jabber now. And if i cant login with gmail credentials it will be more pathetic for me! Thanks anyway. Voted you up.

Comment: @John Which server you have used currently?

Comment: yes Sunil, i have downloaded xmpp framework & also implemented with my project as the direction i found in github.

Comment: @John It will work with gtalk. If you want to test it then first go to XMPPFramework-master/Xcode/iPhoneXMPP folder in downloaded framework. Then open iPhoneXMPP.xcodeproj and go to "iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate.m". Here first uncomment [xmppStream setHostName:@"talk.google.com"];& [xmppStream setHostPort:5222]; then run it.

Comment: @John Hope you will get it.

Comment: Sunil i found those into the "-(void)setupStream" method. I have uncomment them, but still no message is going! Should i have to change anything else?

Comment: @John Are you able to get list of online user now?

Comment: @John Where you have defined function - (IBAction)sendMsg:(id)sender, in AppDelegate or at other class?

Comment: yes sunil i can get the list of user. I have set my action method in other class, not in Appdelegate class.

Comment: Yes sunil. One thing may help u, that i can receive chat message from gmail but can't send.

Comment: @John Where you have setup & implemented delegate method of xmpp? In AppDelegate? If in AppDelegate then please remove- xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init]; & [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; from that function and just use "self.xmppStream" object from AppDelegate class.

Comment: Your modesty brother :) I have given the AppDelegate class at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @John I have checked your code, can you provide me your source code if possible? So i can check it.

Comment: how can I provide u my full source code? Should i provide it here, or any other way?

Comment: @John you can upload your source code to dropbox then give me download link.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am surely going to do that :)

Comment: @John I figure out you problem. Change sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];  to  sharedInstance = (iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: You will able to send message now

Comment: @John In iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate class within + (iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate *)sharedInstance function.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother! You r fabulous! A real boss! I will be grateful to u forever! :)  :)

Comment: can you share some detail I have also same issue ?